# Windows 2008 - Finding out restriction on user accounts

Tags: windows-server-2008

I don't know why but my findings tells me that running my process as "SYSTEM' (LocalSystem), 
can connect me to another server. Other users are completely stopped from doing so.
Is there a way for me to find out what restriction imposed on other users?
Thank you

Comment: is that localservice or system?

Answer (score 0):

kepung,

The **LocalSystem** account doesn't have access to other servers, as indicated by the name.  If you can offer up a bit more information, we might be able to assist if this is still an issue, but as it stand now your question is a bit sparse.